# Let $S^1$ and $[0,1]$ equipped with the topology induced from the discrete metric. Are they homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Let the set $S^1:=\{x\in\Bbb R^2:\|x\|_2=1\}$ but with the topology **not induced from the euclidean norm** (the euclidean norm is just used here to define the elements of the set), instead the topology is induced from the discrete metric defined as

$$d(x,y)=\begin{cases}0,&\text{ if }x=y\\1,&\text{ if }x\neq y\end{cases}$$

Now the set $[0,1]$ have the same topology induced from the discrete metric. We can say in this case that $S^1$ and $[0,1]$ are homeomorphic?

I think that the answer is **yes**. Observe that any bijective function between the sets is continuous because every subset of any of these spaces is open and closed.

Because the sets $S^1$ and $[0,1]$ have the same cardinality then a bijection exists, then we conclude that they are homeomorphic. It is this reasoning correct?

Comment: Yes. My only objection is to the phrase "bijection between the sets". Strictly speaking, a function is always from one set to another.

Comment: @user254665 well, but In my experience a function can be extended, restricted or induced in some other sets, so I think a bit of "redundancy" is not too bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument is correct.

More precisely, if $f: S^1 \to [0, 1]$ is a bijection, then for every (open) set $M \subset [0, 1]$ the preimage $f^{-1}(M)$ is open (since every subset of $S^1$ is open in the discrete topology). Conversely, for every (open) set $N \subset S^1$ the preimage $(f^{-1})^{-1}(N)$ is open in $[0, 1]$.

Comment: Ah, thank you, I needed the confirmation to be totally sure.